# How to create the horizontally mirror inverse of a 2d matrix c++?

Tags: c++, matrix, mirror, inverse

For example if the input is :

```
21 26 31 36
22 27 32 37
23 28 33 38
24 29 34 39
25 30 35 40
```

the output should be :

```
25 30 35 40
24 29 34 39
23 28 33 38
22 27 32 37
21 26 31 36
```

Al the rows are swapped until the middle row.

The first row should be swapped with the last one, the second with the before last one row, etc...

This is my code yet:

```
int A[100][100] = { 0 };
int n, m;
std::cin >> n >> m;


for (int k = 0, j = n - 1; k < j; k++, --j)
     std::swap(A[k], A[j]);
```

`number of rows(n), columns(m), for n, m < 100`
It shows me the same matrix as before.

Comment: How is A defined? How are you verifying that the matrix was flipped?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If `A` is a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, a single call to `std::reverse` is all that's required.

Comment: it s a  ````int [ ] [ ] ````

Comment: What is `m`? What happens if `n` is larger than 100?

Comment: ````number of rows(n), columns(m), for n, m < 100````

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't work? The matrix contains only zeros.

Comment: Given your array -- `std::reverse(&A[0], &A[5]);` -- No need for a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap the two dimensional array using [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int A[100][100] = { {21, 26, 31, 36},
                        {22, 27, 32, 37},
                        {23, 28, 33, 38},
                        {24, 29, 34, 39},
                        {25, 30, 35, 40} };

    std::reverse(&A[0], &A[5]);  // Starting and ending ranges are &A[0] and &A[5]

    // Output results
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            std::cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
25 30 35 40 
24 29 34 39 
23 28 33 38 
22 27 32 37 
21 26 31 36
```

Answer (score 2):

You can swap a two-dimensional array either using the standard algorithm `std::swap_ranges` or by writing "manually" a loop.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t M = 5, N = 4;
    int a[M][N] = 
    {
        { 21, 26, 31, 36 },
        { 22, 27, 32, 37 },
        { 23, 28, 33, 38 },
        { 24, 29, 34, 39 },
        { 25, 30, 35, 40 }
    };

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::swap_ranges( std::begin( a ), std::next( std::begin( a ), M / 2 ), 
                      std::rbegin( a ) );

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < N / 2; i++ )
    {
        std::swap( a[i], a[M - i - 1] );
    }

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
21 26 31 36 
22 27 32 37 
23 28 33 38 
24 29 34 39 
25 30 35 40 

25 30 35 40 
24 29 34 39 
23 28 33 38 
22 27 32 37 
21 26 31 36 

21 26 31 36 
22 27 32 37 
23 28 33 38 
24 29 34 39 
25 30 35 40
```

Pay attention to that variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature. It means that the sizes of an array shall be known at compile time. If you want that it is the user who will enter the sizes then use the standard class template `std::vector`.

If you have an already defined array with some maximum values of its sizes and the user may specify its sub-array then the array should be at least zero-initialized